# Vuex unable to use modules

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am using Vue with Webpacker with Rails. I am having some problem with Vuex, specifially on using modules.

application.js:

```
import store from '../store/store'
Vue.prototype.$store = store;


document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '[data-behavior="vue"]',
    store
  })
})
```

store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';
import itemstore from'./modules/itemstore'
Vue.use(Vuex)

import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
............
  modules: {
    itemstore
  }

})


export default store;
```

itemstore.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';


const itemstore = {
  state: {
    items: [],
},
actions: {
    loadItems ({ commit }) {
        axios
        .get('/items.json')
        .then(r => r.data)
        .then(items => {
            commit('SET_ITEMS', items);
        })
    }
},
mutations: {
    SET_ITEMS (state, items) {
        state.items = items
    }
},
}

export default itemstore;
```

In my component:

```
    mounted () {
      this.$store.dispatch('loadItems')
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState([
            'items'
        ]),
      }
```

First to get the main store imported I need `Vue.prototype.$store = store;`

Secondly once i move those states, actions and mutations from store.js to itemstore.js, items gets undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: itemstore needs to be typed as a module somehow.  I don't use this syntax in my modules. it depends which libraries you are using, but you should check the doc on declaring your module itemstore.

Comment: You shouldn't need `Vue.prototype.$store = store`, that should be automatic. You don't seem to have included an example of something that isn't working, so it's difficult to speculate what the problem might be. How you access the module will depend on whether or not you're using namespacing.

Comment: @TheMikeInNYC I tried also to create the module with const state, const actions and so on but the result is the same.

Comment: @skirtle I updated the answer with an example but basically I moved stuff from store.js to the module and it's not available in components anymore.

Comment: 1. Could you provide an example of the component code, including the error message you're seeing? 2. Could you confirm that you aren't using namespacing? https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing 3. The way you're importing Vue catches my eye. Typically it would just be `import Vue from 'vue'`, without the `/dist/vue.esm` bit on the end. Make sure you're being consistent in how you import Vue across all files or you could end up with multiple copies of the library, each with partial configuration.

Comment: I have added componenet code. I am not using namespacing. The way I import vue with /dist/vue.esm for what I understand is to be able to use components in Rails html.erb views. If I use the normal import I get the warning that I am running Vue runtime only. But yes I am importing it in the same way in the store too.

Comment: 1. Can you confirm that you're importing Vue the same way across all files, in particular `application.js`? 2. Do you get any error messages? If the store action isn't being found there should be an error message. If there are no error messages then I suggest putting console logging in all the relevant store functions to check that they are being called and that all variables have the values you're expecting. 3. Could you elaborate on how you are establishing that *'items is undefined'*. 4. What goes wrong if you remove the `prototype` line? Specifically, what is the error?

Comment: 1 Yes 2 I get error Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined" (being filter applied to items). I added console log to action in module and it DOES shows in console. This brings me a step forward in investigating it, thanks. 3 from error message and Vue Chrome extension in browser. 4 I get error state is undefined.

Comment: Actually I removed prototype now and the store still works (but still the module is not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `namespaced` setting will cause the `actions`, `mutations` and `setters` of a store to be namespaced based on the module name. The `state` of a module, however, is always separated off into its own subtree within `state`, even if namespacing is not being used.

So this won't work:

```js
...mapState([
   'items'
]),
```

This is looking for an `items` property in the root state.

Instead you can use something like:

```js
...mapState({
    items: state => state.itemstore.items
})
```

You might be tempted to try to write it like this:

```js
...mapState('itemstore', ['items'])
```

However, passing the module name as the first argument to `mapState` will only work with `namespaced` modules.

Comment: I got it working by using the second option you suggested and adding namespaced: true to the store module. Lastly I changed this.$store.dispatch('itemstore/loadItems'). Thanks!